# Resampling only $N$ particles out of $N(T+1)$ weighted particles

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, sampling, computational-statistics

I have a bunch of **weighted** particles $(Z^{(i, k)}, W^{(i, k)})$ from a distribution $\mu(dz)$ where $i=1, \ldots, N$ and $k=0,\ldots, T$. These defines the following **empirical approximation**
$$
\hat{\mu}^{N(T+1)}(dz) = \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{k=0}^T W^{(i, k)}\delta_{Z^{(i, k)}}(dz)
$$
It is composed of $N(T+1)$ particles with weights $W^{(i,k)}$ that sum up to one $\sum_{i}\sum_k W^{(i, k)} = 1$.

> **Question**: If I sample $N$ particles $\bar{Z}^{(1:N)}$ from these $N(T+1)$ particles, how are they distributed?

**Edit**: I will resample particles with replacement where probabilities are proportional to weights (similar to Sequential Monte Carlo). Basically, I will sample indeces
$$
A^{(m)}\sim \text{Categorical}(W^{1, 0}, \ldots, W^{1, T}, \ldots, W^{N, 0}, \ldots, W^{N, T})\qquad m=1, \ldots, N
$$
where $A^{(m)}\in \{1, \ldots, N(T+1)\}$ and then I will transform this index into a pair of indeces as
$$
\begin{align}
    i &= \lfloor(m / N)\rfloor + 1 \\
    k &= (m \mod T).
\end{align}
$$

## Attempt

If I sample $N(T+1)$ particles, the new particles will be distributed according to an unweighted empirical distribution
$$
\bar{\mu}^{N(T+1)}(dz) = \frac{1}{N(T+1)} \sum_{t=1}^{N(T+1)} \delta_{\bar{Z}^{(t)}}(dz)
$$
I would be tempted to say that if I only sample $N$ of them, then they will be distributed according to
$$
\bar{\mu}^N(dz) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{t=1}^{N} \delta_{\bar{Z}^{(t)}}(dz).
$$
On one side, this is the definition of empirical distribution, so this must be correct. However, I feel that the fact that I am not sampling the same number of particles that I had before means that I should still have some weights remaining.

Comment: The answer depends on *how* you sample.  Are the probabilities proportional to the weights, or not?  Is the sample obtained with replacement, or not?  What do you mean by "have some weights remaining"?

Comment: @whuber Yes, probabilities are proportional to the weights, and it is sampling with replacement. I have added a section in my answer that explains in more detail. By "have some weights" remaining I mean this: the empirical distribution 
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=1}^N \delta_{\bar{Z}^{(t)}} (dz)
$$
is somewhat "obvious", but uninformative. I would like to find the actual distribution of the particles after resampling. I think this empirical distribution is definitely one way to describe their distribution, but very uninformative. There must be another form involving a ratio of weights.

Comment: Basically, you tell us you are taking a sample from a distribution and asking how the sample will be distributed.  Although one could write an elaborate answer, intuitively there's little to say beyond the obvious.

Comment: @whuber Okay I see. I thought about it and I guess what I am really asking is this. If $\hat{\mu}^{N(T+1)}(dz)$ approximates $\mu$, then what does $\bar{\mu}^N(dz)$ approximate?

Comment: The same distribution: it's a bootstrap sample.

Comment: @whuber maybe that’s what I need to understand. Do you know of any book or resource that explains these concepts using some measure theory? I.e. distributions rather than densities

Comment: Since you are sampling from an atomic distribution, I do not see where you need measure theory.